# Calculate point in 3d space, between two points at specific distance

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, three.js

For a camera movement in three.js I need to calculate point `C` so to move the camera from point `A` to a certain distance `dist` to point `B`.

[image: scheme showing the point to find]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

three.js has methods to do that very easily.

Assuming `a`, `b`, and `c` are instances of `THREE.Vector3()`,

```
a.set( 2, 1, 4 );
b.set( 9, 4, 2 );

c.subVectors( a, b ).setLength( dist ).add( b );
```

three.js r.91

Comment: thx it works perfectly! but could you explain: I'm not sure why you add `b` to `dist` when it seems more logic you subtract `dist` from `b`

Comment: `dist` is a length, it is not a vector. To get to `c`, you start at `b` and add a certain vector `v` of length `dist`. That vector `v` is `c.subVectors( a, b ).setLength( dist )`.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to calculate the coordinates of point `C`, given that it lies on the line between `B` and `A` at the given distance from `B`? This is pretty straightforward using the following steps:

- Calculate the vector from `B` to `A` (this will just be `A - B`).
- Normalize that vector (make it's length 1).
- Multiply that by the distance you want.
- Add that vector to the point `B`.

So a short javascript example:

```js
const A = [2, 1, 4];
const B = [9, 4, 2];

const dist = 3;

function addVectors(v1, v2) {
    return v1.map((x, i) => x + v2[i]);
}

function scalarMultiply(v, c) {
    return v.map(x => x*c);
}

function getLength(v) {
    return Math.hypot(...v);
}

const vecB2A = addVectors(A, scalarMultiply(B, -1)); // Step 1
const normB2A = scalarMultiply(vecB2A, 1/getLength(vecB2A)); // Step 2
const distB2A = scalarMultiply(normB2A, dist); // Step 3
const C = addVectors(B, distB2A); // Final step

console.log(C);
```

Answer (score 0):

Point C is equal to point B minus 'dist' times a unit vector whose direction is AB. So it is quite easy:

vector v from A to B is equal (xB-xA, yB-yA, zB-zA) / distance(AB)

Then C = B - d*v where d is the distance from B you want C to be.